# Thinkpad Volume Buttons not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, thinkpad

I have a xubuntu 18.04 on a Lenovo Thinkpad R60 and the volume hotkeys are not working at all. `xev` gives no feedback either so the buttons seem no to be recognized by the system. How can I make them work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Enable The Hotkeys

Maybe the buttons are not enabled by the `thinkpad_acpi`. You can enable all hotkeys by

```
echo enable,0xffffffff >/proc/acpi/ibm/hotkey
```

Since you have to be root a simple `sudo` will not suffice because it only effects the `echo`. So you have either to become root by `sudo -i` or encapsulate by e.g.

```
sudo bash -c echo enable,0xffffffff > /proc/acpi/ibm/hotkey
```

or

```
echo enable,0xffffffff | sudo tee /proc/acpi/ibm/hotkey
```

Since it is a bitmask you are working with you can enable and disable hotkeys separately. Refer to [module documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/laptops/thinkpad-acpi.txt) for more info.

---

### Make the change permanent

To survive the next reboot you may add the command to your `/etc/rc.local`

If you are using Ubuntu 18.04 or above the file may be missing since `systemd` is handling this. But if existing the file will be used as you can convice yourself by looking into `sudo systemctl edit --full rc-local`.

The file has to be executable and needs a shebang.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo enable,0xffffffff > /proc/acpi/ibm/hotkey

echo 0
```

If you created the file make it executable by

```
chmod +x /etc/rc.local
```

Comment: Note for future readers - The procfs interface `/proc/acpi/ibm/` will be deprecated but should be available in `/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a small improvement on the above.
The original post asks about the volume buttons, I noticed this also affects the brightness buttons that are already working fine on my T60 running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

There are many bugs related to this, one is this one :
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/357673?comments=all
where I found the mask that only enables the volume keys.

So to get that all to work I made the /etc/rc.local file with the following content:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-ThinkPad-T60:~$ cat /etc/rc.local
#!/bin/sh
echo enable,0xfc7fff > /proc/acpi/ibm/hotkey
echo 0
```

As mentioned, make it executable with :

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local
```

Reboot and on the T60, the volume keys work and brightness keeps working as expected.
Thanks for @karlsebal for providing all details.
Feel free to check the bug to see if your problem and solution may help others, thank you.